# Volley String Request does'nt give Response in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I used Volley String request for Post method..but its not giving correct response..When i used JsonObject request then it will give me correct response..I am so confused ,i don't understand what is problem with string request..Please anyone can help me with string request...
this is my code..

```
      StringRequest requestQueue =Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
      String URL ="http://demoangularaims.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/API_NI_ACD_FILL_COMMON_DDL_SP";

      Log.d(TAG, " url=" + URL);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, " response=" + response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d(TAG, " error=" + error);

    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        linkmap.put("p_ENTITY_ID", "2");
        linkmap.put("p_ORGCD", "p01");
        linkmap.put("p_COMPCD", "A0002");
        linkmap.put("p_DIVCD", "");
        linkmap.put("p_USERID", "");
        linkmap.put("p_ACDYR", "");
        linkmap.put("p_TYPE", "ACDYR_DDL");
        linkmap.put("p_FILTER1", "");
        linkmap.put("p_FILTER2", "");
        linkmap.put("p_DEFUNCT", "");

        Log.d(TAG, " MAP=" + linkmap);
        return linkmap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        return headers;
    }


};

 requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


    PostMan OutPut-
```

[image]

Comment: @ i have check both **string request** and  **JsonObject request** both response is same nothing change in response.

Comment: jsonObject request gives correct response to me..@RatilalChopda

Comment: you hit the service in postman what is the response get.

Comment: {"recordset":[{"ID":1718,"TEXT":"YEAR 2017-2018"},{"ID":1617,"TEXT":"YEAR 2016-2017"},{"ID":0,"TEXT":"--SELECT--"}],"recordsets":[[{"ID":1718,"TEXT":"YEAR 2017-2018"},{"ID":1617,"TEXT":"YEAR 2016-2017"},{"ID":0,"TEXT":"--SELECT--"}]],"rowsAffected":[3],"output":{},"returnValue":0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getBody instead of getParams it will work. Since you are using POST method you should add Request body.

```
       @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {                    
                return stringRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8"); //String Request Body with Encoded
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**JsonObjectRequest**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
String URL = "http://demoangularaims.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/API_NI_ACD_FILL_COMMON_DDL_SP";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("TAG", "JSONObj response=" + response);
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("TAG", "JSONObj Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
            }
        });

requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

**Jsonobject Request OUTPUT**

```
D/TAG: JSONObj response={"recordsets":[],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[],"returnValue":0}
```

**String Request**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
String URL = "http://demoangularaims.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/API_NI_ACD_FILL_COMMON_DDL_SP";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("TAG", "String response=" + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("TAG", "String error=" + error);

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

**String Request OUTPUT**

```
D/TAG: String response={"recordsets":[],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[],"returnValue":0}
```

**POSTMAN OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: when i used JsonObjectRequest it will give me responce like....{"recordset":[{"ID":1718,"TEXT":"YEAR 2017-2018"},{"ID":1617,"TEXT":"YEAR 2016-2017"},{"ID":0,"TEXT":"--SELECT--"}],"recordsets":[[{"ID":1718,"TEXT":"YEAR 2017-2018"},{"ID":1617,"TEXT":"YEAR 2016-2017"},{"ID":0,"TEXT":"--SELECT--"}]],"rowsAffected":[3],"output":{},"returnValue":0}

Comment: @Jayashri i check in postman this url please check my edit answer.

Comment: @ Ratilal  Please check my edited question with output in postman