# Volley StringRequest only get 200 status code but no response body

Tags: android, android-volley

I have the following code that makes a Volley StringRequest.
It seems to work fine and returns with 200 status code in onResponse, but that is all i get.

i was expecting a String representation of JSON that held some tokens.

I've seen some posts that say i have to override getBody and not getParams, but using getParams is the only way i can get a 200 from server.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595757/volley-string-request-doesnt-give-response-in-android)

Has anyone any ideas why the String containing the JSON in not sent back in the response?

Response from server:

> E/WebServicesForWebApi: 200

.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, response);


                        iResult.notifySuccess(null, response);







                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, error.toString());

                        iResult.notifyError(error);


                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("client_id", "HKTPEMS");
                        params.put("client_secret", "B83845-9AFDDD-46D");
                        params.put("grant_type", "password");
                        params.put("username", "testuserrandomQWQ2Matty@care.com");
                        params.put("password", "testpasssword");
                        return params;
                    }






                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };


                RequestQueue queue = appObj.getRequestQueue();
                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late, but this is a top google hit for this issue. Take a look at this block from your code:

```
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String responseString = "";
    if (response != null) {
        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
        // can get more details such as response.headers
    }
    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}
```

`responseString` is what will be input to `onResponse()`.

To get the **body** of the response, set `responseString` to:

```
responseString = new String(response.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check the following:**

1)Your Api's JSON response using developer tools.

2)Try using different libraries other than volley.

3)If you are willing to use volley then change your dependency version and code format for network request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);